# Firebase Authorisation using Kotlin & MVVM

Tags: firebase, kotlin, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata

I'm getting myself rather confused setting up my app using MVVP architecture using Kotlin.

Specifically, I am trying to set up Firebase Auth using this structure..

I have been following this excellent article, which is in Java: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336

So I have set up a simple splash screen, and behind this I have created:

**SplashRepository** - connects to the Firestore database

**SplashViewModel** - observes the Repository

**SplashActivity** - observes the ViewModel

Code below:

```js
class SplashRepository {

private val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
private val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
private val usersCollectionRef = firestore.collection("users")
private val user: UserObject = UserObject()

fun checkIfUserIsAuthenticatedInFirebase(): MutableLiveData<UserObject> {
    val isUserAuthenticateInFirebaseMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<UserObject>()
    val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
        user.isAuthenticated = false
        isUserAuthenticateInFirebaseMutableLiveData.setValue(user)
    } else {
        user.userID= firebaseUser.uid
        user.isAuthenticated = true
        isUserAuthenticateInFirebaseMutableLiveData.setValue(user)
    }
    return isUserAuthenticateInFirebaseMutableLiveData
}

fun addUserToLiveData(userID: String): MutableLiveData<UserObject> {
    val userMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<UserObject> = MutableLiveData<UserObject>()
    usersCollectionRef.document(userID).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { userTask: Task<DocumentSnapshot?> ->
            if (userTask.isSuccessful) {
                val document = userTask.result
                if (document!!.exists()) {
                    val user: UserObject? = document.toObject<UserObject>(UserObject::class.java)
                    userMutableLiveData.setValue(user)
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, userTask.exception!!.message)
            }
        })
    return userMutableLiveData
}

}
```

```js
class SplashViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val splashRepository: SplashRepository
    lateinit var isUserAuthenticatedLiveData: LiveData<UserObject>
    lateinit var userLiveData: LiveData<UserObject>

    fun checkIfUserIsAuthenticated() {
        isUserAuthenticatedLiveData = splashRepository.checkIfUserIsAuthenticatedInFirebase()
    }

    fun setUid(userID: String) {
        userLiveData = splashRepository.addUserToLiveData(userID)
    }

    init {
        splashRepository = SplashRepository()
    }
}
```

```js
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupSplashViewModel()
        checkIfUserIsAuthenticated()
    }

    private fun setupSplashViewModel() {
        splashViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SplashViewModel::class.java)
    }

    private fun checkIfUserIsAuthenticated() {
        splashViewModel?.checkIfUserIsAuthenticated()
        splashViewModel?.isUserAuthenticatedLiveData?.observe(this, Observer<UserObject>{
            fun onChanged(user: UserObject) {
                if (!user.isAuthenticated) {
                    this@SplashActivity.goToLoginNewUserActivity()
                    finish()
                } else {
//                    this@SplashActivity.goToLoginActivity(user.userID)
                    this@SplashActivity.goToLoginNewUserActivity()  // just while testing go to same activity

                }
            }
        })
    }


    private fun goToLoginNewUserActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, LoginNewUserActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    private fun goToLoginActivity() {  // Would go to Sites Activity
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, LoginNewUserActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Oh, and here is the user POJO:

```js
class UserObject : Serializable {
    var userID: String? = null
    var userName: String? = null
    var userEmail: String? = null
    var userMobile: String? = null


    @Exclude
    var isAuthenticated = false
    @Exclude
    var isNew = false
    @Exclude
    var isCreated = false
}
```

The app just stays on the Splash Screen, so I think I have missed something while trying to convert to Kotlin, but can't see what!!  Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Hi Scamparelli. I wrote that article and as far as I see your Kotlin code looks fine to me. So you say that it doesn't matter if the user is authenticated or not, you aren't redirected anywhere? Are you sure you have the right permissions?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response. I have set the current rules set on the database:

// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}

On the manifest I have: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  I should note, I have set up a Splash Screen without using a resource.. (not that I think that is the issue).  Is it my POJO?..

Comment: And you have the same behavior? Add a log statement in each part of your if-else statement, which one is triggered?

Comment: It doesn't seem to get there.  I'll have to spend some time debugging a bit later - at least I'm on the right track thanks! Will update when I find!

Comment: My post was moderated (hopefully this comment is ok!), but for completeness, I have updated my question here with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874102/how-to-return-livedata-from-repository