# How to Return LiveData from Repository

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, repository, android-livedata

I just can't see how to chain LiveData from Repo to VM, so I have tried to boil this down to the most simple of example!:

**Fragment**

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
private var mCurrentName = "Blank!"

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val binding: LoginFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.login_fragment, container, false)

    binding.apply {
        loginButton.setOnClickListener{
            loginViewModel.changeText()
        }
    }
    return binding.root
}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    loginViewModel.getCurrentName().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        mCurrentName = it      // I'm expecting mCurrentName to equal "Button Clicked!" when button clicked..
        makeToast()     // Toast works, but variable remains unchanged..
    })

}

private fun makeToast() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, mCurrentName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val firestoreRepository : FirestoreRepository = FirestoreRepository()
private var mCurrentName = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun changeText(){
    mCurrentName = firestoreRepository.changeText()
}
```

**Repository**

```
class FirestoreRepository {

    private val mCurrentName = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun changeText(): MutableLiveData<String> {
            mCurrentName.value = "Button Clicked!!"
            return mCurrentName
    }
```

I'm assuming I have misunderstood how the observer function works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually If you are maintaining `LiveData` in repository, I don't think there's a need of separate `LiveData` in `ViewModel` as well. You just have to observe the LiveData once from the activity. Then make any changes to repository instance directly. So If I have to show it in your code, It might look something like this.

1. Activity class: Change makeToast method to observeCurrentName() like this:

   ```
   private fun observeCurrentName() {
       vm.getCurrentName().observe(this, Observer{ 
           //Toast here 
       })
   }
   ```
2. Your VM:

   ```
   class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
       ...

       fun getCurrentName(): MutableLiveData<String>{
           return repository.getCurrentName()
       }

       fun setCurrentName(name: String?){
           repository.setCurrentName(name)
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Your repository:

   ```
   class FirestoreRepository {

       private val mCurrentName = MutableLiveData<String>()

       fun getCurrentName(): MutableLiveData<String>{
           return mCurrentName
       }

       fun setCurrentName(name: String?){
           mCurrentName.value = name //This will trigger observer in Activity
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Sandesh - this explanation is exactly what I was looking for.  I have implemented and it works perfectly.  I believe from my research that the right place to create the observers in onActivityCreated as shown - hopefully someone can comment if they disagree?

Answer (score 1):

No need to change `MutableLiveData` inside `ViewModel`. Try to pass whatever `Repository` send to `View`. Check below

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val firestoreRepository : FirestoreRepository = FirestoreRepository()

    fun getCurrentName(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return firestoreRepository.getCurrentName()
    }

    fun changeText() {
        firestoreRepository.changeText()
    }
}
```

And also your `FirestoreRepository`

```
class FirestoreRepository {

    private val mCurrentName = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getCurrentName(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return mCurrentName
    }

    fun changeText() {
        mCurrentName.value = "Button Clicked!!"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same explanation as above in a different way, so I have upvoted - thanks!

Comment: can we unit test that repository?

Answer (score 0):

You're changing `mCurrentName` (the LiveData variable itself as opposed to it's contents) after you start observing it.  The guidance seems to be to not use `LiveData` in Repository layer (use Coroutines/Flow instead for example)....but for now you could have something like following (or perhaps use one of the LiveData Transformations)

```
private val mCurrentName = firestoreRepository.currentName()

fun changeText(){
    firestoreRepository.changeText()
}
```